# I am new to Cryptography and I wonder if one can Suggest me Beginner Projects

Tags: resources

Sorry for this kind of a question, but I really like to learn and improve in cryptography. At the moment I am following online lectures from https://class.coursera.org/crypto-011 , can anyone suggest me any resources or some beginner projects or some documentation for reinforcing the information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The course on coursera is similar to the course CS255 given in Stanford university.
You can find the course homepage at [CS255 course homepage](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/). There are many homeworks and projects that you can check.

To further reinforce the information presented, read the pages suggested in the "Readings" of the course syllabus at [CS255 course syllabus](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/syllabus.html)

Comment: It is given from Stanford University Dan Boneh, but I wonder if there is any other stuff, because I am really new and enormously excited